# Access VBA: SQL delete does not work with table including a -?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an application where I want to import data from a tab/worksheet in an Excel file to a table in MSAccess where the table has the same name as the Excel tab.

This works fine for all tables but one and the only difference I can find is that this table has an hyphen '-' in the middle of its name. The error I get is "Syntax error in the FROM instruction" = the row with DoCmd.RunSQL...
If I rename the table to something without the hyphen it starts working for that table as well.
See code below;
myTab is the name of the Excel worksheet and the MSAccess table.

```
' check that the table exists
validTable = False
Set rs = DBEngine(0).Databases(0).OpenRecordset(myTableList, dbOpenTable)
rs.MoveFirst
For i = 0 To rs.RecordCount - 1
    If rs(0) = myTab Then validTable = True
    rs.MoveNext
Next i

' delete old content, import new data
If validTable Then
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    DoCmd.RunSQL ("DELETE * FROM " & myTab & ";")
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, myTab, inputFile, True, myTab
Else
```

How can I solve this? I guess that it is related to how i use strings
This is just a small part in a bigger application so I cannot just change name of the MSAccess table

//

Re-name of the table

Answer (score 1):

Delimit the table name as below:

```
"DELETE * FROM [" & myTab & "];"
```

Delimiting the table name will work even for table names that do not contain the hyphen character.